# CSS - Rounded borders look like two buttons overlapping

Tags: java, css, javafx, formatting

Here is the picture:

[image]

My background is white (you can see the little gap between the two corners of two different buttons). I have 4 buttons in that picture, not 8 overlapping

The buttons' backgrounds are all black, the border is white. The buttons are 40px in height.

I would like the buttons to have rounded edges/corners, not to be a black box. The window is running on Java.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.button{
-fx-font-size: 12pt;
-fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
-fx-background-color: #000000;
-fx-border-radius: 20px;
-fx-border-color: #ffffff;
-border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: can you provide all the css for that window please?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thank you all, the problem has been resolved (-fx-background-radius added). The window in the image had no css applied to it, so everything was set to default (hence the white background you can see behind the buttons, in fabian's example the background was blue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the only style that applies to the `Button`s is the rule you define, it's sufficient to set the `-fx-background-radius` property. The white "dots" at the corners of the buttons make me doubt this.

The following should achieve the desired behaviour though:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Button button = new Button(Integer.toString(i));
        button.getStyleClass().setAll("button");
        vbox.getChildren().add(button);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### style.css

```css
.button {
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-pref-width: 200px;
    -fx-pref-height: 40px;
    -fx-min-height: -fx-pref-height;
    -fx-max-height: -fx-pref-height;
    -fx-background-radius: 20px;
    -fx-border-radius: 20px;
    -fx-border-color: white;
}
```

[image: result screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! It was the -fx-background-radius that helped to remove the extra corners and make the buttons look really round